# How store a large file into SQL Server 2008 and retrieve all of it?

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, sql-server-2008

My problem is do with a SQL Server database.

I successfully stored data into a SQL Server table from C# with this code:

```
 internal static void SaveAutocadFileOnDataBase(string MapCode, byte[] dataElecMap, string dataElecMapName,byte[] dataCivilMap, string dataCivilMapName, byte[] dataArchiMap, string dataArchiMapName,byte[]dataMechaMap,string dataMechaMapName)
        {
            string sqlcommand = string.Concat("INSERT INTO AutoCadFiles VALUES ('", MapCode, "' , ", "cast ('", dataElecMap, "' as varbinary(max)),", " '", dataElecMapName, "' ", " , cast ('", dataCivilMap, "' as varbinary(max)) ,", " '", dataCivilMapName, "' ", " , cast ('", dataArchiMap, "' as varbinary(max)) ,", " '", dataArchiMapName, "' "," , cast ('", dataMechaMap, "' as varbinary(max)) ,", " '", dataMechaMapName, "' ", ")");  ExecuteNonQuery(sqlcommand);
        }
```

and retrieve it with this Code:

```
    internal static DataTable RetriveMaps(string MapNumber, string MapType)
    {
        string s = MapType + "Name";
        string SqlCommand = string.Concat("SELECT ", MapType, " , ", s, " FROM AutoCadFiles WHERE MapCode='",MapNumber, "'");
        return GetBinaryFiles(SqlCommand);
    }

    private static DataTable GetBinaryFiles(string SqlCommand)
    {
        SqlConnection SqlConnction = null;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlCommand sqlcom = GetConnection(SqlCommand, ref  SqlConnction);
        SqlDataReader sdldr = sqlcom.ExecuteReader();
        dt.Load(sdldr);
        return dt;
    }
```

I successfully get file from dataTable and save it into the filesystem. But the stored file volume is 0 byte

Or 13 Byte very less than stored file in database.

Comment: Abbas, are you missing code here..? where do you save it to the `FileStream` ..?

Comment: You should [read about how to avoid **SQL injection attacks**](http://www.a2zdotnet.com/View.aspx?Id=64#.URKpR2d9uK8) in your code! You're currently highly vulnerable ....

Comment: "I successfully stored data" how do you know? (It wasn't successful). Did you even look at the contents of the file? Read a tutorial on how to do this.

Comment: If you show some effort to debug yourself, and you don't find the bug, I'll tell you what the bug is. It is not that hard to find. You can do it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're retrieving a single row at a time, this simpler code would do the work for retrieving the data:

```
        string fileName;
        byte[] fileread;

        SqlCommand command;
        SqlConnection connection = MyGetSqlConnection();

        connection.Open();

        command = new SqlCommand("Select dataElecMapName From AutoCadFiles  Where MapCode = @MapNumber", connection);
        command.Parameters.Add("@MapNumber", SqlDbType.Int).Value = MapNumber;
        fileName = (string)command.ExecuteScalar();
        command.Dispose();

        command = new SqlCommand("Select dataElecMap From AutoCadFiles  Where MapCode = @MapNumber", connection);
        command.Parameters.Add("@MapNumber", SqlDbType.Int).Value = MapNumber;

        fileread = (byte[])command.ExecuteScalar();

        string tempPath = MyFunc.GetTempDirectory();

        FileStream fs = new FileStream(tempPath + fileName, FileMode.Create);
        fs.Write(fileread, 0, fileread.Length);

        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(tempPath + fileName);

        fs.Close();
```

**EDIT**
Use this code to convert your file:

```
    public static byte[] ConvertFileToBytes(string location, ref string FileName) 
    { 
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(location, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

        BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(fs);

        byte[] data = reader.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);

        fs.Close(); 
        return data; 
    }
```

Comment: but this is not my problem and when i say  "I successfully stored data" I say this about for storing data in sql  usr thank you.

Comment: Cesar Vega thaks a lot .test your code. this is good, but my problem is not resolved.it work exactly my code working. this is code that I using for converting data to array of bytes        public static byte[] ConvertFileToBytes(string location, ref string FileName)
        {
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(location, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            byte[] data = new byte[fs.Length];
            fs.Read(data, 0, System.Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
            fs.Close();
            return data;
        }

Comment: But I think Bug not exist in my Code.I think  var Binary(max) Max is not true SQL Type For save data bigger than 2mb.I need SQL type for My fields type. Can You Help  Me?

Comment: varbinary(max) can hold up to 2^31-1 bytes. That's not the problem. The bug has to be in the way you're storing the data. The only problem I could see is that your casting the FileStream.Length to Int32, while it is of type **Long**, but unless you're storing very large files that should not be a problem. See my extended answer.

Comment: hi Cesar I test your Code but My bug does not resolved. See when I upload array of bytes it lenght Is very Larg but when I restroe It from sql It lenght is 13

Comment: My Problem is resolved Thank You Cesar And all of my friends. My Bug Was in Saving Data Into Sql.It From SQL injection attacks.

Comment: That's what we told you since the beginning! :)

Comment: What if I have file with size more than 1.6 GB? here your code will break with error.